# How to $pull Multiple Objects from an Array by Multiple Criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a situation where I have to pull multiple values from an array based on a request.

State of things in the database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fb8fdf5e3227c637891ca8"),
    "description" : "Testing service",
    "name" : "test-service",
    "endpoints" : [ 
        {
            "uri" : "/api/test1",
            "method" : "GET",
            "description" : "test1",
            "noAuthRequired" : true,
            "allowedByDefault" : true,
            "allowedRoles" : ['admin']
        },
        {
            "uri" : "/api/test2",
            "method" : "GET",
            "description" : "test2",
            "noAuthRequired" : true,
            "allowedByDefault" : true,
            "allowedRoles" : ['admin']
        },
        {
            "uri" : "/api/test3",
            "method" : "GET",
            "description" : "test3",
            "noAuthRequired" : true,
            "allowedByDefault" : true,
            "allowedRoles" : ['admin']
        }
    ]
}
```

Requests list multiple endpoints which I have to be removed from database array. Example of a JSON request:

```
{
    "endpoints": [{
        "uri": "/api/test1",
        "method": "GET"
    },
    {
        "uri": "/api/test2",
        "method": "POST"
    }]
}
```

When this request comes and gets processed, it should remove endpoint with URI /api/test1 and method GET. It should NOT remove endpoint with URI /api/test2 and method GET beacuse request stated that POST /api/test2 should be removed, and since it isn't present in DB only GET /api/test1 gets removed.

I have tried doing it this way, using Mongoose:

```
router.route('/services/:id/endpoints').delete(function(req, res) {
    ...
    model.service.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': req.params.id },
    { $pull: { 'endpoints': req.body.endpoints } },
    function(err, srv) {
        ...
    });
});
```

And that does nothing at all.

```
router.route('/services/:id/endpoints').delete(function(req, res) {
    ...
    model.service.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': req.params.id },
    { $pullAll: { 'endpoints': req.body.endpoints } },
    function(err, srv) {
        ...
    });
});
```

This does nothing as well.

```
router.route('/services/:id/endpoints').delete(function(req, res) {
    ...
    model.service.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': req.params.id },
    { $pullAll: { 'endpoints': { $in: req.body.endpoints } } },
    function(err, srv) {
        ...
    });
});
```

And this removes ALL the endpoints in DB, which it shouldn't.

I have settled on using async:

```
var pullCalls = [];
req.body.endpoints.forEach(function(endpoint) {
  pullCalls.push(function(callback) {
    model.service.findOneAndUpdate({
      '_id': req.params.id
    }, {
      $pull: {
        'endpoints': {
          'method': endpoint.method,
          'uri': endpoint.uri
        }
      }
    }, function(err, srv) {
      if (err)
        return callback(err);
      callback(err, srv);
    });
  });
});

// TODO: try doing this without async in a single query
async.parallel(pullCalls, function(err, srv) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500);
    res.json({
      'success': false,
      'response': err
    });
  } else {
    res.json({
      'success': true,
      'response': 'endpoints_removed'
    });
  }
});
```

And that works, but I'd like doing it without async in a single mongoose query. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so going to hate this, but:

```
{ "$pull": { "endpoints": { "$or": req.body.endpoints } } }
```

Will work just fine.

The [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator expects data in exactly the same format as you are submitting. And [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) already works on inspection of the array field elements by nature.

And of course [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) means "either", which basically translates to *"anything that matches either of these conditions, needs to be pulled"*.

So as long as `req.body.endpoints` is actually represented as an array like you say, then that is actually the correct argument to [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Comment: Thank you that worked! I didn't even know $or existed :D

Comment: @FilipVoska You were actually *so close* with `$in`, but of course that operator expects only a "list" of "values" and not a "full document expression". So props for your attempts, and that's a lot better than a lot of people asking here ever do. Also you might be confused that `$in` is not a operator "specifically" for arrays. It is rather the reverse, being an "array of arguments to match a field", regardless if that field is actuallly an array itself. The best way to think of it is as *"shorthand for $or"*. Which in fact, it really is.

Comment: try $pullAll instead of $pull